# Parsing Json Array Object in specific format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON is:

```
var json = '{"name":"GeoFence","coordinate":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.coordinate);
```

But i need to set the values of coordinates as follows:

```
var myTrip=[new google.maps.LatLng(1,2),new google.maps.LatLng(3,4),new google.maps.LatLng(5,6)];
```

Comment: Do you expect `myTrip == obj.coordinate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
var json = '{"name":"GeoFence","coordinate":[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]}',
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var myTrip = [];
for (var i = 0; i < obj.coordinate.length; i++) {
    myTrip[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.coordinate[i][0], obj.coordinate[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the coordinates and create a new object for each, and add that to `myTrip`:

```
var myTrip = [];

for(var i=0; i < obj.coordinate.length; i++) {
    myTrip.push(new google.maps.LatLng(obj.coordinate[i][0],obj.coordinate[i][1]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the collection of the coordinates:

```
var myTrip = getCoordinate ();

var getCoordinate = function(){
        var ret = [];

        for(var i = 0, length = coordinate.length; i < length; i++){
           ret.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate[i][0], coordinate[i][1]))
        }

       return ret;
}
```

Comment: Code without **explanation** is not an answer.